# C language convert integer values to 0x.. hex byte values and store into an nx2 array

Tags: arrays, c, char, integer

I'm trying to use an SPI protocol to create a set of triangle/sawtooth waves. The main goal is to streamline the speed of the process of creating discrete sample values to send to a DAC. I understand how to send the values to the DAC. What I'd like to do is pre-calculate the values and store them in an array. That way, I don't have to process each value in real time. My idea is to just create an array bigger than I'll need and continually erase and overwrite it if a new frequency/waveform is requested.

The algorithm part is fairly straightforward, and I don't need to get into any of that. But the SPI is expecting a set of two byte values in the hex (unsigned char) form 0x.. I would like to create a for loop that generates these values in decimal and converts them to unsigned char values and stores them in an array as the for loop iterates. The hex values need to be separated into two bytes (the upper byte 0x9. , and the lower byte 0x..). Basically, these bytes are bit shifted into a 16 bit register starting with the MSB. the 9 in 0x9. is the control signal. the voltage level is represented by the next 10 bits, and the last two bits in the 16 bit register are don't cares. Once the array is appended, I can use the values generated as a voltage level map that loops until the user enters a new value. That way, nothing has to be calculated while the DAC is outputting values.

As previously stated, I can get the algorithm to do all this. Where I'm getting hung up is converting an int to the proper size unsigned char and storing it into an array inside a for loop.

Comment: That’s a weird SPI if it takes ASCII in and not just binary data. What system is this?

Comment: If you talk about hex values, do you mean the representation in source code? Because it is just that, a textual representation. An integer variable stores its value in binary, and all you see as a human is some kind of textual interpretation. -- You don't need to change the base system. Calculate your number, do some bit magic (for the control signal, the 10 bit extension and the trailing bits) and store the resulting 16 bit number. That's it.

Comment: If you are generating the values on the fly, you should only care about the actual numeric values of the bytes, not a textual representation of the numeric values. If `val` contains a 10 bit value to be converted to a pair of bytes, it sounds like you need the value of the first (m.s.) byte to be set according to the expression `(0x90 | (val >> 6) & 0x0F)` and the value of the second (l.s.) byte to be set according to the expression `((val << 2) & 0xFF)`.

Comment: This is technically the case, but the two bytes are actually being shifted in as part of a single 16 bit word. If there's an easier way to separate the first 8 bits from the second 8 bits without converting to hex, that would work also. I'm pretty certain the compiler converts everything to decimal values. Hex is just a convenient way to send bytes to the various registers on the microcontroller. This is for a Dragon12 board.